# Mysql Query- for each date max 3 datas

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

these is my DB table data,{ i have maintained only one Table}

I need to fetch max 3 data from each start_date,

give me any idea to develop query,,

Comment: What do you mean - max 3 data? Please explain and show desired result.

Comment: Do you want each date's data or you want data for any single date?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775820/sql-give-me-3-hits-for-each-type-only

Comment: If there are 10 rows in start_date - which rows should be shown? They should be sorted to select exact three rows in a group.

Comment: @SaharshShah each date's data.. dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table1 b ON a.start_date = b.start_date AND a.event_id <= b.event_id
GROUP BY a.event_id,a.start_date
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
ORDER BY a.start_date
```

Comment: Thank You sel,, thanks for your query.. i got the result but small error getting as ** unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE **

Comment: unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE

Comment: Not sure what is the error about but it didn't seem like query error. You could try out @Devart solution.

Answer (score 1):

I may suggest you this query -

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*) pos FROM table t1
    LEFT JOIN table t2
      ON t2.start_date = t1.start_date AND t2.event_id <= t1.event_id
  GROUP BY
    t1.start_date AND t1.event_id
  ) t
WHERE
  pos <= 3;
```

It selects 3 rows with min `event_id` in a `start_date` group.

Comment: Thanks for idea Devart,, but sel got query for my question

Comment: Was anything wrong? It select 3 first records per `start_date`.

Comment: I just gave an answer to your question.

Comment: Of course You are right.... for getting answer i gone through `GROUP BY t1.start_date,t1.event_id` removed and to `,` important one is your code execution time took more when compare to @sel....... THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWER I LEARNED MANY THING FROM YOUR ANSWER!!!! @Devart cheers!