# Find out the last two rows for a user

Tags: mysql

I have this table in which each user can have more than 1 row in the table, so I wanted to find out the top two rows for each user.

I saw this link and tried the solution

[SQL - Give me 3 hits for each type only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775820/sql-give-me-3-hits-for-each-type-only?lq=1)

```
SELECT user_fk, order_number, @num := IF( @group = user_fk, @num +1, 1 ) AS row_number, @group := user_fk AS dummy
FROM summary
ORDER BY  `user_fk` ASC
```

I use the above query to see if the row_number increments, but it doesnt. Any idea why?

Comment: Appears to be working for me (although I would suggest initializing your user defined variables): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3172f0/2

Answer (score 0):

it is working

enclose it in inline view

[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4156a/5)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_fk, order_number from 
(SELECT user_fk, order_number, @num := IF( @group = user_fk, @num +1, 1 ) AS row_number, @group := user_fk AS dummy
FROM summary
ORDER BY  `user_fk` ASC) as x 
where row_number<=2
```

I think you have missed some part of query.

Comment: not sure if it affects the query, my user_fk is of type int(5) and order_number is varchar(255). Have around 13k rows in this table. use above query as well. never finished running. thats why i trying the sub query