# get first x rows using in()

Tags: php, mysql, database

It's not a duplicate question because I saw and didn't find my answer in those questions.

Table `example` :

```
id  type   title
1   3      sth1
2   4      sthelse
3   3      sth2
4   3      sth3
5   4      sth4
6   4      sth5
```

I want to get 2 first rows of each type. like this:

```
id  type   title
1   3      sth1
3   3      sth2
2   4      sthelse
5   4      sth4
```

I played with group_by nd limit but look at this forexample:

```
SELECT * FROM `example` WHERE type IN(3, 4) LIMIT 2;
```

It gives me :

```
id  type   title
1   3      sth1
2   4      sthelse
```

and by using group_by(type) it gives only 1 row from each type.

Note: I don't want to make a loop for that in php that it will be about 15 or 20 queries but if it can be done using 1 query that's nice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - Give me 3 hits for each type only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775820/sql-give-me-3-hits-for-each-type-only)

Comment: The only thing that make this isn't duplicated is `... rows using in()` :)

Comment: @RubahMalam That's a pretty trivial change...

Comment: masters, I don't know why I don't get the expected result from that exact query. ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/4775879/5097040 ) It gives me all rows. :( @Mike

Comment: @RubahMalam Same previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ist a sample how you can do it.

1) sort all results by **type**

2) then count the row of each type

3) get only ROWs where recno < 3

```
SELECT  
  @nr:=IF(@lastid = e.TYPE , @nr:=@nr+1 ,1) AS recno,
  @lastid:=TYPE AS last_type, e.* 
  FROM `example`e,
  (SELECT @lastid:=0, @nr:=0) tmp
WHERE TYPE IN(3, 4) 
HAVING recno < 3
ORDER BY TYPE;
```

*Result:*

```
MariaDB [tmp]> SELECT
    ->   @nr:=IF(@lastid = e.TYPE , @nr:=@nr+1 ,1) AS recno,
    ->   @lastid:=TYPE AS last_type, e.*
    ->   FROM `example`e,
    ->   (SELECT @lastid:=0, @nr:=0) tmp
    -> WHERE TYPE IN(3, 4)
    -> HAVING recno < 3
    -> ORDER BY TYPE;
+-------+-----------+----+------+---------+
| recno | last_type | id | type | title   |
+-------+-----------+----+------+---------+
|     1 |         3 |  1 |    3 | sth1    |
|     3 |         3 |  3 |    3 | sth2    |
|     1 |         4 |  2 |    4 | sthelse |
|     3 |         4 |  5 |    4 | sth4    |
+-------+-----------+----+------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you nice idea. Can you tell me why this (stackoverflow.com/a/4775879/5097040 ) doesn't work in this situation?

Comment: Yes, it also works fine, but they say "where  row_number <= 3" that means less OR EQUAL 3 that are 3 ROWS of each type and they also sort "order by type, title" first by type AND then by title. so the order is a little bit different to my. If you remove ",title" from the sort, its the same

Comment: So surely I'm wrong somewhere as that query gives me all rows while I'm having the exact table. Anyway, sry if it's a duplicate.

Comment: change the where in the other sample to "WHERE  row_number < 3;" and it work. only it return two other rows